# Creating handlers from an interface

Tags: go

Let's say I have this interface

```
type Selecter interface {
    Select(vars ...string) error
}
```

and I want to make handlers that pretty much just return JSON forms of that interface after it has called the `Select` function. Like this:

```
func MakeHandler(s Selecter) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //... do some stuff to get vars ...
        if err := s.Select(v1, v2); err != nil {
            //... blah blah errors ...
        }
        b, err := json.Marshal(s)
        if err != nil {
            //... blah blah errors ...
        }
        w.Write(b)
    }
}
```

So if `CoolType` is a `Selecter` I can do something like this

```
type CoolType struct {
    CoolString string `json:"cool_string"`
    CoolInt int       `json:"cool_int"`
    CoolBool bool     `json:"cool_bool"`
}

func (c *CoolType) Select(vars ...string) error {
    // fill up c using vars
    return nil
}

// this looks kinda ugly to me too
fn := MakeHandler(CoolType{})
```

The underlying problem I have with this is that `s` is an interface and uses a pointer. This would make this not safe in goroutines since `s` could be modified between the calls to `Select` and the call to `Marshal`.

I really think this is the way I'd like to go about implementing this since it is fairly concise and easy for me to change, but I think I'm missing something. I could use `reflect` or change the `Selecter` interface to have `Select` return an `interface{}` instead since I don't particularly care what the type is. Then I'd just make a new copy of the type in every implementation of `Select` I guess. Or a mutex would work. Or perhaps the better way to do this would be to have all of my `Selecter` types just implement `ServeHTTP` and be an `http.Handler`.

Anyway I assume people have tried something like this and have come up with possibly more elegant solutions so I'd like to hear some ideas.

Comment: not to answer the big design problem, but you can implement a interface with struct other than struct pointer. meaning turn `func (c *CoolType) Select(vars ...string) error` to `func (c CoolType) Select(vars ...string) error`, to make sure not change the struct content in some method.

Comment: Yea I think I could just do that. I was hesitant because the structs can be quite large. I am mostly just interested in other solutions. What do you mean by not to answer the big design problem? Do you see a big glaring flaw in this way to go about this? Sometimes you get so stuck on the first way you wrote something that it is almost impossible to see the obviously better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid of mutations pass a copy of the value. To do it you probably have to change your interface to something like:

```
type Selecter interface {
    Select(vars ...string) (Selecter, error)
}
```

And change your Select method to take a value receiver to fulfill the interface. It would be `func (c CoolType) Select(vars ...string) (CoolType, error)`

Then pass your `s` as a value instead of pointer and call Select like:

```
if s, err := s.Select(v1, v2); err != nil {
     //... blah blah errors ...
}
```

You can argue that you lose information about the type, but you already lost it while passing the value as a Selecter interface.

But in general your implementation is good. My feeling is that in Go elegant is something different than in other languages. I'd say that in Go elegant is readable, maintainable and accurate - not bureaucracy and trying to protect you from yourself.

Comment: Yea I guess that is the way I'm probably going to have to do it. Nice to have other people look at things sometimes